# Error about code coverage: No object file for requested architecture

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, llvm

I am learning code coverage for iOS，and I want to create code coverage reports for IOS unit tests，and I use

```
“xcrun llvm-cov report -instr-profile */Coverage.profdata */CodeCoverage/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XXX.app/XXX”
```

But always have the error：

> Failed to load coverage: No object file for requested architecture

How could the error be solved?

Please help.